# Use References that already exists in other project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i have a problem regarding using the References in other Project.

Let say I have Project A and Project B in one solutions. I have all references needed in Project A, but Project B also need to use some of the references contains in project A.

How can I call the references in Project A into Project B? Do I need to use the word import on the top of the code?

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Explain what part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019) you do not understand.

Comment: If by `References` you mean the referenced assemblies, than add the same references in both Projects.

Comment: There's no such thing as "calling a reference". A reference is basically a statement to a project that an assembly exists. As far as a project is concerned, it's references are the whole world. In that project, you can refer to any type that is declared in one of those referenced assemblies.  As far as a project is concerned, any type declared in an assembly that isn't referenced does not exist. If project B needs to refer to a type then project B needs to reference the assembly it's declared in. It's that simple. What project A references is irrelevant.